# Rate of growth of a Basel-like infinite product involving primes

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, infinite-product

Inspired by [Euler's solution to the Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler.27s_approach), consider the function
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{5^2}\right)\cdots \\
&= \prod_{\text{$p$ prime}}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{p^2}\right).
\end{align}$$
This is a function whose zeros are precisely the prime numbers and their negations. Its oscillations grow quite rapidly:

[image]

A semi-log plot of $|f(x)|$ shows that the growth is superlinear but apparently subexponential.

[image]
[image]

**Question:** What is the asymptotic rate of growth of the oscillations?

<sup>(N.B. To create the plots I approximated the function using the first $1000$ primes, i.e. up to $p=7919$.)</sup>

Comment: Kind of reminds of the prime counting function, but not quite.  :D

Comment: Come to think of it, $\exp(x/\log(x+1))$ does match the growth rather well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDvJz.png

Comment: Not about asymptotes, but related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsumoto_zeta_function

Comment: Hm, what do you mean by "What is the asymptotic rate of growth of the oscillations?"?  Are you asking for the asymptotic behavior of the top of the humps?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.